# TikTok detect login with Selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to TikTok with Selenium, but every time it gives me the message "Too many attempts. Try again later.".
If I enter my email and password manually it works, if I use Selenium it doesn't.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Email or username']"))).send_keys(email)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Password']"))).send_keys(password)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']"))).click()`
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: did you check what you have in variables `email`, `passowrkd`? Maybe you send wrong values. Maybe you have `space` or `new line` in variable and you don't see it but server treats it as wrong email or password.

Comment: Yes, they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites have services that can detect Selenium and then block you.

The three main ways of avoiding Selenium-detection by websites are:

1: [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)

2: [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) in undetected mode. (Use `--undetected` or `--uc` as a `pytest` command-line option.)

3: [selenium-stealth](https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth)

Comment: undetected-chromedriver is perfect